# Getting Variables from Module Which is Being Imported

Tags: python

main:

```
import fileb
favouritePizza = "pineapple"
fileb.eatPizza
```

fileb:

```
from main import favouritePizza
def eatPizza():
    print("favouritePizza")
```

This is what I tried, however, I get no such attribute. I looked at other problems and these wouldn't help.

Comment: this looks very much like circular import. sounds a very bad idea to me to import stuff from `main`

Comment: https://stackabuse.com/python-circular-imports/

Comment: Why do you even need to import in fileb? the `favoritePizza` variable does nothing in that file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is classic example of circular dependency. `main` imports `fileb`, while `fileb` requires `main`.

Your case is hard (impossible?) to solve even in theory. In reality, python import machinery does even less expected thing — every time you import anything from some module, whole module is read and imported into global(per process) module namespace. Actually, `from module import function` is just a syntax sugar that gives you ability to not litter your namespace with everything form particular module (`from module import *`), but behind the scenes, its the almost the same as `import module; module.function(...)`.

From composition/architecture point of view, basic program structure is:

- top modules import bottom
- bottom modules get parameters from top when being called

You probably want to use `favouritePizza` variable somehow in `fileb`, i.e. in `eatPizza` functions. Good thing to do is to make this function accept parameter, that will be passed from any place that uses it:

```
# fileb.py
def eatPizza(name):
    print(name)
```

And call it with

```
# main.py
import fileb
favouritePizza = "pineapple"
fileb.eatPizza(favouritePizza)
```

Comment: can i import a whole dictionary as a paramater?

Comment: Parameters being "accepted"/"expected", not imported. Yes, you can import and accept almost anything, python does not pass actual objects/structures, only references to them.